# View a row of datagridview in a dynamically created form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, nullreferenceexception, dynamically-generated

I am new to vb.net and working on VS 2012.
I have a datagridview which displays the rows of an ms-access 2007 database table. I created a form (with Text Boxes and Add/Update/Cancel buttons - all dynamically (using code)), which shows data when a row of the datagridview is selected.

Now, I want the values of the fields (of the selected row) to be displayed in the textboxes and any changes made to the textboxes to be added/updated in the database, depending upon the button clicked. How can it be done? That is, how to:

1. Fill in the textboxes with row values, and,
2. Update/Add the changes to the database?

Basically, the real problem is referencing the dynamically created controls on the form! I am getting `null reference exception`.

Please help!
Many thanks!

Comment: Among other things, if you create controls at runtime, you have to work out a way to either maintain a reference to them or find them in the `Controls` collection

Answer (score 0):

To reference the dynamically created controls, just store these controls in Form variables.

**Fill in the textboxes with row values**

```
 dim v as object = MyDataGridView.CurrentRow("MyColumName").Value
 MyTextBox.Text  = ""
 if NOT IsDBNull(v) Then MyTextBox.Text  = v.ToString()
 End If
```

**Update/Add the changes to the database**

When you validate the edition form, update the dataTable and, assuming that you have loaded the dataTable with a DataAdapter, call the DataAdapter update function:

```
 myDataAdapter.Update(myDataSet, "myDataTableName")
```

Comment: I am using "Add" button to append to the table now, but UNABLE to reference ANY of the textBoxes or the Values in them. Error is that the cotrol is 'not declared'. Also, if I DirectCast the controls, I get NullReferenceException. Pls suggest.

Comment: I want to do something like this:  Friend Sub AddNewClient(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Button AddClient clicked!" & txtClientId.text) 

    End Sub

Comment: The VS reports that txtClientId is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets take care of `NullReferenceException` - you need to maintain references of your controls. For example, you create form dynamically like this, `Dim f as New Form()`. In this case, you can add controls to it, etc but you can't have internal control of the declaration. So, you add controls, `f.Controls.Add...`

I think, what you've done is you created a form on which you dynamically add controls. In this case you can do

```
Dim ctrlList As New Dictionary(Of String, Control)()
Dim txtBox1 As New TextBox()
txtBox1.Location = New Point(0, 0) 
' set txt box here . . . 
Me.Controls.Add(txtBox1)
ctrlList.Add("txtBox1", txtBox1) ' reference this to get to controls dynamically
```

How to fill your controls. There are 2 main methods. One - programmatically, another by using bindings.

Since you do things dynamically, here is what you can do  - build the screen totally dynamically. For this if, for example, your select statement will be `Select col1, col2, col3 from table`, you will create a text box for each column and place it in desired location. Now you can obtain `DataRow` from selected row in grid and set text of textbox as

```
ctrlList("col1").Text = dr("col1")
```

Where "col1" will be both - name of key for your control and column. You can also name control this way too.

Second method is using Bindings. You can bind your grid and text boxes. This way you wire your controls upfront and then you don't need to set `text` property.

With this system, you can totally dynamically load any data. So, if your `select` will have 10 columns, you will have 10 controls, etc. Once you finished with screen, you need to remove all of them from form and collection and get ready to reload new set of controls.

But I have to say, you need a bit of experience to develop really functional system like this.